# TexLive pkg psv. Error message "Unable to open display device"

Tags: texlive-2018

TeX Live is running on a Windows 10 PC.

I have installed the `psv` package into the TeX Live by means of the Manager. `psv` complains when run. The error message mentions "display device" and I do not understand what is meant.

Hopefully someone can find where I do wrong.

My command:

```
c:\sys\texlive\tlpkg\tlpsv>psv \proj\listings\GTX660.pdf
```

`psv` opens a window. It shows:

> ```
> GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20)
> Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
> This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
>
> **** Unable to open the display device, quitting.
>
> This is wxLuaGhostscscript.
>
> Lua: Error while running chunk
>
> psv.wx.lua:1511: Failed to start Ghostscript
> stack traceback:
>   [C]: in function 'error'
>   psv.wx.lua:1511: in function 'StartGS'
>   psv.wx.lua:2230: in function 'Main'
>   psv.wx.lua:2242: in main chunk
> ```

Added a few hours later:

More searches on the web showed me a solution out of the problem with psv:

It has been used to display rulers and grids. These are available in the Acrobat through

View Show/Hide Rulers&Grid

Sorry to have posted this!

So, I abandoned the psv and instead used the Adobe Acrobat that gave me the information that I needed.

Comment: Would you mind tell me what's the solution of your problem?